# How to click a button on form load using C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, form-load

How do i click a button on foam load using C#?
My button is called: `btnFacebookLogin`

I have tried this following:

```
private void Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   btnFacebookLogin.PerformClick(); 
}
```

I am using WinForms C# .NET 4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be sure to link your handler **after** InitializeComponent() and to **Load** event

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Load += Form1_Shown;
}

private void Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   btnFacebookLogin.PerformClick(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there a specific reason you need to actually click the button?

I would just move the code in the click event into a function, then call that function from both the load event and the click event. It will get around the need to call `click()`

For instance:

```
private void Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   DoFacebookLogin();
}

private void btnFacebookLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoFacebookLogin();
}

private void DoFacebookLogin()
{
    //Do Work here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this :

```
public void Form1_Load(object s, EventArgs e){
  btnFacebookLogin.PerformClick();
}
```

And I consider that you know that the following event handler should exist in your code behind :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hi");
    }
```

Comment: Sadly this doesnt work for me. I even tried putting in MessageBox.Show("test");

Comment: what u posted is : Form1_Shown and you should change It to Form1_Load , It absolutely works

Answer (score -1):

@PriceCheaperton : you can call an event from another event the simplest example is here.

C# :

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1_Click(sender, e);
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Calling event from an event...");
    }
}
```

ASPX :

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
</form>
```

Output :
[image]

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy : the implementation is the same for the scenario mentioned by 'PriceCheaperton'. its just that I am into Web technologies. I have posted the solution in web forms. and the same can be implemented even in the windows forms without any C# code change.

Comment: Question is tagged with *winforms* tag. Also I don't understand how screenshot of browser helps here